# Ember call an action on the application route from within the application routes setupController

Tags: ember.js

I've setup a basic example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. I am using `setupController` from within the application route, and have an action called `addToSidebar`. Within setupController I want to call the action but get the error:

`Nothing handled the action 'addToSidebar'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.`

Where else can I send the action from in my application route?

**Code**

routes/application.js

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
  controller.set('numbers', [1, 2]);

  var someImportantVariable = true;

  if (someImportantVariable) {
    this.send('addToSidebar');
  }
  },
  actions: {
    addToSidebar: function() {
      var controller = this.controller;
      controller.get('numbers').addObject(controller.get('numbers.length') + 1);
    }
  }
});
```

application.hbs

```
 <div class="sidebar">
   Pets:
   {{#each numbers as |num|}}
     {{num}}
   {{/each}}
 </div>
 <div class="mainArea">
    {{outlet}}
 </div>
```

In my real life example the variable `var controller = this.controller;` will be decided by some more complex logic coming back from the forfilled models.

**JS Bin**
I've setup a jsbin that shows the error I receive:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pedato/edit?html,css,js,output

Uncomment `this.send('addToSidebar');` to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap sending action in `Ember.run.next`:

```
if (someImportantVariable) {
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
        this.send('addToSidebar');
    });    
}
```

It makes sure that it action will be fired at later time, when all stuff is properly initialized.

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mipeden/edit?html,css,js,output)